# use android ndkr8 compile ffmpeg2 through cygwin on windows

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, ffmpeg, cygwin

I want to compile ffmpeg for using in android. When i use "make" command,one error show as below:

```
arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: libavdevice/libavdevice.so:1:1: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting $end
```

How can i fix it.

Comment: Sounds like you did not [setup a standalone toolchain](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html). What parameters did you pass to `./configure`?

Answer (score 0):

When building ffmpeg for Android, add

```
--disable-avdevice
```

when you run `./configure`